# Algebra x in UILabel

Tags: ios, math, fonts, uilabel, algebra

I am trying to get an algebra “x” in a UILabel, what can I do. Is there a font in swift that I can use, can you create one or is there a Unicode character for the algebraic “x”.

Comment: Check out the “Emoji & Symbols” viewer in macOS. In the Keyboard section of System Preferences, turn on “Show keyboard and emoji viewer in menu bar”. The viewer has a section called “Mathematical Symbols” which contains the Unicode character “MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X”.

Comment: @GaryMakin Thank you, that works, can you post this as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOS has a “Emoji & Symbols” viewer that can be shown using a menubar item (`Edit > Emoji & Symbols` or (`^` + `⌘` + `Space`)). The viewer has a section called “Mathematical Symbols” which contains the Unicode character “MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X”: , as well as many other useful symbols.

The viewer has a small window version and a larger window version. The “Mathematical Symbols” section only appears in the larger window version. You can swap between the two with the icon that appears in the top right of the window.

You can also have a menu appear in the right side of the menu bar that contains this menu item. To get this menu to show, open `System Preferences` and go to the `Keyboard` section. In there, turn on “Show keyboard and emoji viewer in menu bar”. By default, this menu items shows the larger version of the window.

Comment: The "Emoji & Symbols" menu appears in the Edit menu of virtually every macOS app you run.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was so used to the way I described that this `Edit` menu item had escaped me. The initial presentation is different, but the one you described can be turned into the other with the icon in the top right of the window.